# ErrorException error issue in laravel how can i redirect this another custom error page

Tags: laravel

When I got an error in laravel site then i have received this error page.I want to redirect to another page which I have created custom looks like a valid error page.

enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x8nu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your .env file (in your project's root) set false for app_debug -> 
**APP_DEBUG=false**

Then create a file named **500.blade.php** that contains your custom html css in **(resources\views\errors)**

Done.

(for others errors like 404 , 503 , just change the name of file to that error code)

[More information Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#custom-http-error-pages)

Comment: after creating 500.blade.php in error directory my custom error page will be redirected automatically to 500 blade or not? or it would require some changing in any file?

Comment: error***s*** directory, not error .
it's not redirect, when error occurred, 500.blade.php will render instead of default error page.
remember you should set app_debug false in your .env

Comment: thanks for given positive response to my question...solved it